# PHP: get a string inside a particular string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a lot data into one string and i want to get some particular chunks of data.

Example of my data:

```
lorem ipsum fashjdf hsakj sdhsdaf something: 'data' jhjkhf akjh fa kjhjhk fdasjh kafsdj hkadf 
current database: 'databasename' alot of lorem ipsum data current username: 'username'
and jet more lorem ipsum data and so on
```

Now i want to get the string after "current database" and the one after "current username". BUT i want to assign them to the strings $database and $username.

I know there is a regular expression like

```
preg_match_all("/'(\w*)'/", $output, $result);
```

But in the lorem ipsum-data there is a lot of other text with quotes. And i just want to get only thoose two strings and assign them to there variables.

Does anyone please can help me to figure this out.

Comment: Use current database and current username in your pattern.

Comment: That pattern which you have is not even remotely going to match your those values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$subject = "lorem ipsum fashjdf hsakj sdhsdaf something: 'data' jhjkhf akjh fa kjhjhk fdasjh kafsdj hkadf 
current database: 'databasename' alot of lorem ipsum data current username: 'username'
and jet more lorem ipsum data and so on";

preg_match("/current database: '([^']+)'/", $subject, $matches);
$database = $matches[1];

preg_match("/current username: '([^']+)'/", $subject, $matches);
$username = $matches[1];

var_dump($database);
var_dump($username);
```

Comment: It works. Apparently the string had more spaces then it was showing me. So it was "current database:     'databasename'" thats why my regex didn't worked out.